# Python: Why I can print a Unicode character on one line of code, but the same Unicode character causes an error when I try to print it later?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, ascii

I'm writing a Python program using `BeautifulSoup4`, and when I fetch an HTML element that contains a stylized quotation mark `u'\u2019'` I am able to print out the ***whole*** element like so:

**Code:**

```
print "Using song: %s" % (song_link)
```

**Result:**

```
Using song: <a href="http://www.songlyrics.com/anna-kendrick/cups-pitch-perfects-when-im-gone-lyrics/" title="Cups (Pitch Perfect’s “When I’m Gone”) Lyrics Anna Kendrick">Cups (Pitch Perfect’s “When I’m Gone”)</a>
```

But then when I try to print out ***just the text*** of that element, it fails:

**Code:**

```
print "Song text: %s" % (song_link.text)
```

**Result:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is this happening?  Why does this work one moment and then not work the next?  It is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your first case is a byte string.  The output of your second case is a Unicode string.  Unicode strings are implicitly encoded to the terminal encoding, or `ascii` if the terminal encoding could not be determined, which results in your error.

Not knowing your environment, you need to determine why printing Unicode strings defaults to encoding in `ascii`, or explicitly encode the string yourself with `.encode('utf8')`.

Comment: Just calling .encode('utf8') on the string before printing it seems to have fixed it - thanks!